# Getting following error in LTSpice simulation : “Too few nodes…”

Tags: ltspice

I am doing simulation using LTspice and getting error as Too few nodes. 
I am using three external library components/parts. 
Could you please help me to identify where I am missing. 
Thank you.

D1 - DI_PDS3100

U2 - ZXLD1371_PSPICE

M1 - ZXMN6A08E6 are the three components from external library.

.ASC file

Version 4
SHEET 1 1932 1264
WIRE -320 -192 -1072 -192
WIRE -128 -192 -256 -192
WIRE -992 96 -1024 96
WIRE -864 96 -912 96
WIRE -848 96 -864 96
WIRE -800 96 -848 96
WIRE -720 96 -736 96
WIRE -640 96 -656 96
WIRE -560 96 -576 96
WIRE -432 96 -496 96
WIRE -304 96 -432 96
WIRE -128 96 -128 -192
WIRE -128 96 -224 96
WIRE -128 128 -128 96
WIRE -1072 144 -1072 -192
WIRE -1024 144 -1024 96
WIRE -1024 144 -1072 144
WIRE -1024 176 -1024 144
WIRE -992 176 -1024 176
WIRE -864 176 -864 96
WIRE -864 176 -912 176
WIRE -848 208 -848 96
WIRE -832 208 -848 208
WIRE -432 208 -432 96
WIRE -432 208 -768 208
WIRE -176 208 -240 208
WIRE -128 256 -128 224
WIRE -240 320 -240 208
WIRE -176 320 -240 320
WIRE -48 320 -96 320
WIRE -48 352 -80 352
WIRE 160 352 144 352
WIRE 368 352 368 320
WIRE -384 384 -416 384
WIRE -272 384 -304 384
WIRE -256 384 -272 384
WIRE -80 384 -80 352
WIRE -80 384 -176 384
WIRE -48 384 -80 384
WIRE 192 384 144 384
WIRE 288 384 256 384
WIRE -80 416 -80 384
WIRE -48 416 -80 416
WIRE 256 416 256 384
WIRE 256 416 144 416
WIRE -848 448 -848 208
WIRE -48 448 -848 448
WIRE 144 448 128 448
WIRE 368 448 368 432
WIRE 368 448 144 448
WIRE -1072 480 -1072 144
WIRE -1072 480 -1120 480
WIRE -1008 480 -1072 480
WIRE -944 480 -1008 480
WIRE -880 480 -944 480
WIRE -128 480 -880 480
WIRE -48 480 -128 480
WIRE 192 480 144 480
WIRE -1072 496 -1072 480
WIRE -1008 496 -1008 480
WIRE -944 496 -944 480
WIRE -880 496 -880 480
WIRE -48 512 -96 512
WIRE -48 544 -112 544
WIRE -1072 592 -1072 560
WIRE -1008 592 -1008 560
WIRE -1008 592 -1072 592
WIRE -944 592 -944 560
WIRE -944 592 -1008 592
WIRE -880 592 -880 560
WIRE -880 592 -944 592
WIRE -112 592 -112 544
WIRE -112 592 -880 592
WIRE -1008 624 -1008 592
FLAG 592 16 0
FLAG 592 -64 Vin
FLAG -1120 480 Vin
FLAG -1008 624 0
FLAG -128 480 A
FLAG 160 352 A
FLAG -128 256 0
FLAG 496 16 0
FLAG 496 -64 PWM
FLAG -96 512 PWM
FLAG -272 384 TADJ
FLAG 192 480 TADJ
FLAG 288 384 0
FLAG -416 384 0
FLAG 368 320 Vin
SYMBOL voltage 592 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL cap -1088 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=5.63 Rser=0.0203188 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C1210C105K1RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL cap -1024 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=5.63 Rser=0.0203188 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C1210C105K1RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL cap -960 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=5.63 Rser=0.0203188 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C1210C105K1RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL cap -896 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 0.1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM21BR72A104KA37" type="X7R"
SYMBOL diode -256 -208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value DI_PDS3100
SYMBOL res -896 80 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 0.47
SYMATTR SpiceLine pwr=0.125
SYMBOL res -896 160 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 0.39
SYMATTR SpiceLine pwr=0.125
SYMBOL LED -720 112 R270
WINDOW 0 72 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value NSPW500BS
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL LED -800 112 R270
WINDOW 0 72 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value NSPW500BS
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL LED -560 112 R270
WINDOW 0 72 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D7
SYMATTR Value NSPW500BS
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL LED -640 112 R270
WINDOW 0 72 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMATTR Value NSPW500BS
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL ind -320 112 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 68µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine Ipk=4.74 Rser=0.0913 Rpar=6405.6 Cpar=0 mfg="Coilcraft" pn="MSS1278T-683"
SYMBOL res -80 304 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 2.2
SYMATTR SpiceLine pwr=0.125
SYMBOL voltage 496 -80 R0
WINDOW 3 -66 135 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 3.3 1 0 0 20m 1000)
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL res -288 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -160 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 1.8k
SYMBOL cap 256 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 330p
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R72A331JA37" type="X7R"
SYMBOL cap -768 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=5.63 Rser=0.0203188 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C1210C105K1RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL nmos -176 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value ZXMN6A08E6
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\ZXLD1371_PSPICE 48 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL res 352 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 47k
TEXT 448 -200 Left 2 !.tran 2
TEXT 432 136 Left 2 !.lib PDS3100.spice.txt
TEXT 424 176 Left 2 !.lib ZXMN6A08E6.spice.txt
TEXT 432 96 Left 2 !.lib ZXLD1371.spice.txt

[image]

Comment: Lets see the LTSpice schematic. That will help us help you. Most likely cause is that one of your external library parts has a model which doesn't match its symbol. the full error report would also help us.

Comment: I have added the LTSpice schematic here.

Comment: Circuit: * C:\Users\Documents\LTspiceXVII\New Proposed LED Driver.asc

Fatal Error: Too few nodes: eee8c5c7a2bc4b01f045f303678664e7916da0bae22e8cb0bba041dd67c69ce448ea70148a9ac1670c8926c1ac5057c8ccfcd77bf87ca9dc6004e157994bc9bf

Comment: It looks like you have an encrypted PSpice model. So you can't use it in LTspice.

Comment: @G36 : When I open external parts symbol, it not encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

> "The PSpice models for the TI's parts on the web are encrypted and can only run in PSpice version 15.7 or higher. In order to import them into another simulator that supports PSpice models, an unencrypted model would be required. TI requires an NDA for release of the NexFET models in an unencrypted format. If you have an NDA with TI, we can provide you the unencrypted models.
>
> Another option would be to use TINA-TI, a free spice simulator. We can provide the .TSM macro files for the NexFETs that will work in TINA-TI."

About Britt Brooks - Online Design Tools
Biography

I have worked at TI for more than 25 years as a product engineer, transistor level modeling engineer, and now as a SPICE macro modeling engineer. I currently support WEBENCH® tools, PSpice macro models for Power products, and TINA-TI.

---

LTspice is from another company  Analog Devices, Inc